# passing file extension as argument to powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am using this powershell command to flatten a directory.
The line below works fine:

```
    Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Filter "*.mp3" |  Move-Item -destination ..\Duplicates\
```

But when the line is used as a script, I am not sure how to pass `"*.mp3"` to the script below. 
    I am getting an `InvalidArgument: error`.

```
FlattenDirectory.ps1 . "*.mp3" ..\Duplicates\
```

```
    # FlattenDirectory.ps1
    Param(
        [string]$From,
        [string]$Ext
        [string]$To
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `,` missing in your `Param` block.

```
Param(
    [string]$From,
    [string]$Ext, # here
    [string]$To
)
```

Comment: with the comma in place, the move part worked, but the script hanged and I got this error: The script failed due to call depth overflow.

Comment: What are you using to invoke the script? Also, is this your full script, or just a snippet?

Comment: I am using powershell, not the cmd. Yes, it is the full sript

Comment: How are you getting a call depth overflow then? Are you using a different script to invoke this one?

Comment: I have rerun the test. And again the same problem. The script failed due to call depth overflow.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException        I am using the powershell command line to run the script as as follows > FlattenDirectory.ps1 . "*.mp3" ..\Duplicates\

Comment: It works fine for me. Sorry, I don't know how to help you further without more information.

Comment: Declaring a variable to receive the argument from outside the script like this(see below) worked for me. See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/
 
$param= $args[0]